# How to retrieve a parameter from callModule() in R

Tags: r, shinydashboard, reactive

I am developing a shiny dashboard. I need to get the user name alone from the login module. I am using callModule() for performing the authentication of the dashboard.

The **ui.R** code looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyauthr)
library(shinyjs)
shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
  # must turn shinyjs on
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  # add logout button UI 
  div(class = "pull-right", shinyauthr::logoutUI(id = "logout")),
  # add login panel UI function
  shinyauthr::loginUI(id = "login"),
  # setup table output to show user info after login
  tableOutput("user_table")
)
)
```

The **server.R** code looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyauthr)
library(shinyjs)
library(DBI)
library(RMySQL)
library(dplyr)

# dataframe that holds usernames, passwords and other user data

user_base <- data.frame(
  user = c("user1", "user2"),
  password = c("pass1", "pass2"), 
  permissions = c("admin", "standard"),
  name = c("User One", "User Two"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # call the logout module with reactive trigger to hide/show
  logout_init <- callModule(shinyauthr::logout, 
                            id = "logout", 
                            active = reactive(credentials()$user_auth))


  # call login module supplying user and password cols
  # and reactive trigger
  credentials <- callModule(shinyauthr::login, 
                            id = "login", 
                            data = user_base,
                            user_col = user,
                            pwd_col = password,
                            log_out = reactive(logout_init()))

  print(class(credentials))
  # pulls out the user information returned from login module
  user_data <- reactive({credentials()$info})
  #user_name <- reactive({credentials()$user_col})
  print(user_data)

  output$user_table <- renderTable({
    # use req to only render results when credentials()$user_auth is TRUE
    req(credentials()$user_auth)
    user_data()
  })
})
```

When I try the above code, I get the following output [image: output].

However, I am not sure about displaying the **user** alone rather the displaying the password, permissions and name.Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily manipulate the data you want to display:
Here are several:

1. `user_data` only gives you back username

`user_data <- reactive({credentials()$info[1]})`
Because `credentials()$info` is just an array of characters, you can select only the first one: user name

2. `renderTable` only shows user name:
   You can do:

   `output$user_table <- renderTable({
   req(credentials()$user_auth)
   user_data()[1]
   })`

or

`output$user_table <- renderTable({
 # use req to only render results when credentials()$user_auth is TRUE
    req(credentials()$user_auth)
    userData <-user_data()
    userData[1]
  })`

Just by the same logic as the first one: at the end, `user_data` it is only some character you want to filter